# Why is async Web Service call not responding?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have a web service, which I am accessing from two different applications currently, WPF and MVC. In both applications I am calling the auto-generated async web service methods.

The WPF application works just fine, so far, but when calling the same async web method from the MVC application, the web service just never responds. The trace for that service is nearly empty and while debugging I can see that the method is just terminating as it should be.
In addition, different async methods can be called from the mvc app without any problem.
Configuration for binding and endpoint are exactly the same in both applications.

That's really freaking me out, since this behavior seems so randomly and I just cannot figure out what's going wrong.
The non-async call works and even other async methods can be called from the MVC app.

That's how I call the method:

```
try 
{
    var result = await this._serviceChannel.GetResultsAsync(newerThan);
    return result;
}
..
```

And that's the method of the service:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "GetChangedResults", ReplyAction = "GetChangedResults")]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "GetResults")]
public IEnumerable<Results> GetChangedResults(DateTime newerThan)
{
    using (ResultUnitOfWork ruow = new ResultUnitOfWork())
    {
        return ruow.GetChangedResults(newerThan);
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks and Greetings

**Edit:**

I have changed the method body to just return NULL directly after the call - also no response:

```
public IEnumerable<DcLecturer> GetChangedLecturers(DateTime newerThan)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How is the service generated ? Can you post the actual code of the service ? of the GetResultsAsync

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic deadlock situation.
Use `ConfigureAwait` when awaiting for the result:

```
try 
{
    var result = await this._serviceChannel.GetResultsAsync(newerThan).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result;
}
```

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Where do you see a deadlock? He's not calling `.Result` or `.Wait` in any code posted.

Comment: And why do you think using `await` causes a deadlock?

Comment: Which part of of the article says that using `await` causes a deadlock? Have you read the article?

Comment: That has done the trick. Thanks a million! Using await is not equal to ConfigureAwait, but ConfigureAwait jumps in, when the awaiting fails, (very) broadly speaking - is that true?

Comment: .. and thanks for the link - would have been my next question :)

Comment: @Yuval, the `await` itself does not cause deadlock, but the combination for ASP.Net context and `GetResultsAsync` (which requires another thread) does.
I think it is fairly explained in point 5. The top-level method synchronously blocks on the Task returned by GetJsonAsync. This blocks the context thread.

Comment: .. and it does not do that always, since I have been using this concept very often without any issues before. Seems more like it is promoting deadlocks. However, I will correct that ..

Comment: Then that is *the real issue*. It isn't the `await`, it's the fact that he's synchronously blocking on the async method call, which he shouldn't do. `ConfigureAwait(false)` is a workaround, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try to better understand the reason and improve my code.

Comment: .. me as well. Workarounds should not be used to resolve bad concepts.

Comment: @Dusan your diagnosis was right and I had the same hunch. But there was no evidence to support it since he was not calling Wait/Result in code posted here. But then again 95% of the time when something async "hangs" it is this same mistake.